# why is $[0,\frac{1}{4})$ open in $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

> [image]

See [here](http://www-groups.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/%7Ejohn/MT4522/Lectures/L8.html)  for original text.

In this example 2, why does $[0,\frac{1}{4})$ would be the open set of $[0,1]$, what about the point $0$, it's $\epsilon$-neibourhood does not fully contained in the set $[0,\frac{1}{4})$.

Moreover, is $[0,\frac{1}{4})$ neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you talk about $\epsilon$-neighbourhood you have to ask "with respect to what?". You are right that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ **but in $\mathbb{R}$**. While in $[0,1]$ the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $0$ is $[0,\epsilon)$ since in $[0,1]$ there are no elements smaller than $0$.

So $[0,\frac{1}{4})$ is open in $[0,1]$ but it is not open (nor closed) in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: really helpful!! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Remember, $B_X(a,r) =\{\color{red}{x\in X} : d_X(a,x) < r\}$. The part you are overlooking is the "$x\in X$".